# Can I add phone number as a searchable field on Advanced search Page?

Tags: search

We are currently running on civiCRM version 4.1. Can I add phonenumber as a searchable field on Advanced search Page?

Answer (score 7):

Sure thing. Just upgrade to version 4.4 or later and it will be there :)

Comment: Coleman, thanks for responding. I have to provide proof to my boss that this is available. Do you have any documentation that shows that it has been added. We are planning to upgrade to version 4.6 in the coming months.  Is this available in the list of features.  Is this configured out of the box.

Comment: Edward - yes, it's available out of the box.  For proof, go to http://demo.civicrm.org and go into Advanced Search on the demo site.  You can then show your boss directly or take a screenshot for them!

Comment: Coleman, Thanks for responding. I really appreciate it.

Comment: John G. Thanks for providing the link to the demo web site. It's very helpful!